# Pandas converting String object to lower case and checking for string

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below code

```
import pandas as pd
private = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx","Pri")
public = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx","Pub")
private["ISH"] = private.HolidayName.str.lower().contains("holiday|recess")
public["ISH"] = public.HolidayName.str.lower().contains("holiday|recess")
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Is there anyway to convert the 'HolidayName' column to lower case and then check the regular expression `("Holiday|Recess")`using `.contains` in one step?

Comment: If you convert the terms to lowercase, they'll never contain uppercase letters like `H` or `R`..

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was an oversight when I was typing out my example. Have fixed it.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
private["ISH"] = private.HolidayName.str.contains("(?i)holiday|recess")
```

The `(?i)` in the regex pattern tells the `re` module to ignore case.

---

The reason why you were getting an error is because the Series object does not have the `contains` method; instead the `Series.str` attribute has the `contains` method. So you could avoid the error with:

```
private["ISH"] = private.HolidayName.str.lower().str.contains("holiday|recess")
```

Comment: nice! is this in the docs somewhere? is this a pandas-specific thing, or something else? guessing something else.

Comment: @grisaitis: The vectorized string methods are [documented here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/text.html#text-string-methods). 
The use of `(?i)` to do case-insensitive pattern matching is part of the Python `re` module's [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). (Search for the string `(?iLmsux)`).

Comment: Sad that the best answer to this problem involves deep knowlege of RE.  N00bs  (such as myself) are looking to chain the str operations.

Comment: just to add, if you want an exact match, then `df[(private['HolidayName'].str.lower() == "holiday")]` should work

Answer (score 24):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you could use the keyarg 
case : bool, default True, If True, case sensitive.

```
private["ISH"] = private.HolidayName.str.contains("holiday|recess", case=False)
public["ISH"] = public.HolidayName.str.contains("holiday|recess", case=False)
```

Comment: FYI - checked all 3 methods (chaining str, using regex, using case=False).....turns out regex is the fastest, case=False method is about 1.25 times longer, chaining str is about 1.06 times longer